# symfony twig html tags </div>

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm fairly new with twig, so I'm having a little trouble. How add  tag to end of variable name?

```
{{ item.description|raw'</div>' }}
```

is correct?

description is with html tags

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to add your tag out from twig:

```
{{ item.description|raw }}</div>
```

However, you could use concatenation:

```
{{ (item.description ~ '</div>')|raw }}
```

Comment: Dear whey use {{ (item.description|raw) ~ '</div>' }} all html code is &lt;li&gt;WordPress 3.8 Ready.&lt;/li&gt;

Comment: If you use a wysiwyg editor like tinymce, sometime outputed data is already html encoded. So even if you use |raw filter, it will not works. Change your wysiwyg config to output raw data (For example with tinymce : http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:entity_encoding)

Comment: don't use wysiwyg editor html data is fetched of other website

Comment: can you dump your data ? {{ dump(item.description) }} If your dumped data is already entity encoded, you have to decode it with php : http://php.net/html_entity_decode

Comment: Yes it is correct if I use {{ item.description|raw }} but with {{ (item.description|raw) ~ '</div>' }} back &lt;li&gt; codes

Comment: perfect. Thank you very much, best wishes.